# How to resolve CriticalWarning, Certainty for DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors "

Tags: c#

```
    public ValidateDBServerDetail(
        TollPlus.TBOS.DataContracts.SAC.DashBoard.DBServerDetail  objDBServerDetail)
{
AddRule(new ValidateRequired(objDBServerDetail.ServerName, "Error Message"));
}
```

I am using the parameter then how can i resolve this issue

I am getting the warning as

> CriticalWarning, Certainty 95, for
>   DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors

How to resolve this issues?

Comment: Are you calling a virtual method from your constructor?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The message seems pretty clear: don't call virtual methods in with constructors. Without knowing what your constructor is trying to do, it's hard to help you further...

Comment: The subclasses might override a method, and they haven't been constructed yet.